# How to get a row from a dynamically created type in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Say I have two classes mapped for a database I'm using with nHibernate : `shop_info` and `customer_info`.

I can use `mySession.Get<shop_info>(ID)` or `mySession.Get<customer_info>(ID)` (`mySession` being the nHibernate session in my code) to get a specific row by its ID for the according class `shop_info` or `customer_info`.

How (if possible) could I use this method and specify the class to be retrieved from a string that I would get during runtime ?

Here's an example of how what thought would do it :

```
Type dynamic_type = Type.GetType("CurrentAssembly.shop_info, CurrentAssembly");
var dyn_object = mySession.Get<dynamic_type>(object_id);
```

But (obviously since I'm asking) this didn't work and I couldn't find a way to use something dynamic for the type parameters between <>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the non generic `Get()` from `ISession` to return an `object`:

```
var dyn_object = mySession.Get(dynamic_type, object_id);
```

And then convert it in the type you want:

```
var typedObject = Convert.ChangeType(dyn_object, dynamic_type);
```

Comment: I really don't know how I didn't manage to find this method while it was right under my nose, thank you very much for your reply this was exactly what I was looking for.